# What is difference between Disable 'OWA for Devices' and 'Outlook on the web'

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app

What is difference between Disable 'OWA for Devices' and  'Outlook on the web'

I want to disable user from access the email from any browser, but want user to access email using Outlook and Mobile devices such as iPhone etc..

So far i `disabled` `Outlook on the web` under Email Connectivity, but i am still able to access same account from browser using `https://www.office.com/

What am i doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

> > **What is difference between Disable 'OWA for Devices' and 'Outlook on the web'**

According to **GaryZhu_MSFT3613**'s reply in the thread "**[How Do I Disable OWA For Mobile Devices](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-disable-owa-for-mobile-devices/d5755b6b-68c0-464d-9d2d-b12ecc7e667c)**", the feature "**OWA for Devices**" is to **enable/disable the access to the owa app on mobile devices** instead of **enable/disable the access to outlook.office.com on mobile devices' browser**.

To disable the access to **outlook.office.com** on the browser, as you did, we could disable the feature "**Outlook on the web**". However, because of the cache of the browser, the access of OWA could still be available after disabling, you could try to disable the feature for a few times more or clean the cache of the browser.

Comment: Hi, i'm here to confirm the progress of your thread, if the issue has been solved, you could mark the best answer to help people who have the same problem. Have a good day:)